Problems with the reuse of a develeped library
I have been developing a library for quite some time. Its structure is as follows :
pgk1                # central library
  ...               # sub-packages and modules
  requirements.txt  # relevant dependancies 

This library is only for internal purposes and can't be loaded to PyPI, also it can't be installed in the central site-packages of my interpreter.
So my idea was to set a central place for such libraries under PYTHONPATH, so that it would be possible for me to make easily an import as from pkg1 import XY for every new project, which I'm starting.
The problem is that the pkg1 has its requirements.txt for the venv, which are unknown / not installed in the current project(current venv) and ImportError will be raised on runtime.
For sure I could copy the requirements.txt from the pkg1 into the new projects requirements.txt, but this would be tedious.
I'll be very thankful for every tip, which will help me to re-develop an easier workflow with such a dependancies.


Create your pkg1 library as a package and define all the dependencies in the package.
Build your package (either manually or using something like the build package) to generate a Wheel or Source Distribution (SDist).
Create a local PIP repository and include the Wheel/SDist for pkg1 in the local repository. (This can be as simple as a directory containing the Wheel/Source Distribution files created from the build and HTML index files that contains links to the files. You can automatically generate it from a directory using the piprepo package but its not too hard to write your own script if you don't want a 3rd-party dependency. Or if you want you can set up a local web-server for the repository.)
When you want to use pkg1 in a different project then include it in the requirements.txt/setup.py/pyproject.toml for the new project.
When you want to install it into the virtual environment, if you are using requirements.txt, use the --extra-index-url command-line option:
python -m pip install --extra-index-url /path/to/your/local/repo -r requirements.txt

To install the dependencies for the new project. It will try to fetch pkg1 from the local repository (and also try to fetch it from PyPi, which assuming that there is not another package of the same name, would fail - but that is not an issue if it is in the local repository). If you have created the package properly in step #1, then installing pkg1 will also try to install the dependencies of pkg1 and, recursively, their dependencies.

